# FlatMapLatest in C# Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

How can I simulate flatMapLatest in C# Reactive extensions. For example I need rewrite this code to C#:

```
screenChanged
   .flatMapLatest {
        return apiProvider.someApiCall()
   }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what your reference is for `flatMapLatest`, but `.Select(_ => apiProvider.someApiCall()).Switch()` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes! This is it. Thanks.